# pick words from a file which are recursive and print them out in another file, python

Tags: python

take input from a file (stringsToTest.txt) and output only the strings that are 
palindromes to another file (stringsArePalindromes.txt). Ignore spaces, capitalization, and punctuation

when determining whether the string is a palindrome, but write the original string to the file if it is a palindrome

this is what i had so far:

```
def ispalindrome(text):
    file=open(str(text),"r")
    a=file.readlines()
    #f=open(str("stringsarepalindromes.txt"),"w")
    for x in a:
        nomorepunc=x.replace("!","")
        nopunc=nomorepunc.replace(".","")
        nospace=nopunc.replace(" ","")
        samecase=(nospace.lower())
        morecase=samecase.replace("?","")
        evencase=morecase.replace("'","")
        cases=evencase.replace(":","")
        #print(cases)
        words=str(cases)
        c=words.split()


        if len(c) < 2:

            print(c,"true")
            #f.write(y)

        if c[0]!= c[-1]:
            print("no")



        return ispalindrome(c[1:-1])
    #open("stringsarepalindromes.txt")"""
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem with what you have so far? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Here's a tip: `def is_palindrome(a): return a == a[::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the punctuation:

```
remove = "!.?':,"   # put all characters you want to remove in here
```

To get rid of these characters, and lower all the letters in your string, you can say (where `x` is your string)

```
x = "".join([i.lower() for i in x if i not in remove])
```

After that, you can test for a palindrome by simply checking the reversed string.

```
x == x[::-1]
```

Comment: when i run the code it only runs through the first line of the file. How should i put return in the loop without making it stop after the first line? Or can i just eliminate the forloop completely?

Comment: Take the file read out of your loop. Then you can call your `def isPallendrome()` function within your loop line-by-line

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all punctuation and write the palindromes to a new file:

```
import string
def ispalindrome(text):
    with open(text) as f,open("output.txt","w") as f1: # use with to open your files to close them automatically
        for line in f:
            test = line.strip().lower().translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation).replace(" ","") # remove punctuation and whitespace
            if test[::-1] == test: # if the line and line reversed are equal, we have a palindrome
                f1.write(line) # write original line to outfile.txt
            print "Is {} a palindrome? {}".format(test,test[::-1] == test) # just a line to show you what is happening
```